# Problemas con buscador scope de Laravel

Tags: laravel, buscador

Tengo el siguiente problema de que no me funciona el buscador *scope de Laravel*.

El error que me muestra es este:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method Nom does not exist.

Este es mi modelo *Movie*:

```
protected $table="movies"
```

En esta función se hace la unión de las tablas de la bases de datos `movie` y `genres` para mostrar todos los atributos de la tabla `movies` y solo el atributo (`genre`) de la tabla `genres`:

```
public static function Movies(){
    return DB::table('movies')
        ->join('genres','genres.id','=','movie.genres_id')
        ->select('movies.*','genres.genre')
        ->get();
}
```

... y esta función es la que hace del buscador *scope de Laravel*, este también se encuentra en el modelo *Movie* quedando así:

```
public function scopeNom($query, $nombre){
    return $query -> where('name','LIKE',"%$nombre%");
}
```

... y este es mi controlador **MovieController.php**:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $nombre = $request ->get('nom');
    $pelis = Movie::Movies()
         ->Nom($nombre);
    return view ('peliculas.index',compact('pelis'));
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema te da?

Comment: Movie? MovieController?? y lo llamas con User... en que modelo esta tu scope?,  para que la union de dos tablas?

Comment: ya corregi algunas cosas , y ese es el error q me sale de que el methodo Nom no existe

Comment: En tu controlador `MovieController` si estas importando por su *namespace* al modelo `Movie`? de este modo `use Movie;`

Comment: lo estoy importando como use IMSUR\Movie;

Comment: IMSUR es el namespace y Movie es el modelo

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente éstas intentando hacer un buscador de está forma:

```
  $pelis = Movie::return DB::table('movies')
    ->join('genres','genres.id','=','movie.genres_id')
    ->select('movies.*','genres.genre')
    ->get();
    ->Nom($nombre);
```

**laravel** te muestra que el método Nom no existe porque ni siquiera estas llamándolo y/o llegando a él.

Si hicieras lo siguiente:

```
$pelis = Movie::return DB::table('movies')
    ->join('genres','genres.id','=','movie.genres_id')
    ->select('movies.*','genres.genre')
    ->Nom($nombre)
    ->paginate();
```

Puede funcionar